# jquery call/run toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

```
$("#foo").toggle(function(){alert("A");},function(){alert("B");});
```

I would like to call this toggle so the "A" part will be run (alert A) and the "B" part will be the next one (if I click on foo). Is it possible? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is already doing it

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/5f57f

```
<div id="foo">test</div> 

<script> 
$(function(){ 
    $("#foo").toggle(function(){alert("A");},function(){alert("B");}); 
    $("#foo").click();

}); 

</script>
```

alerts A,B,A,B,A,B on clicking, A on startup

Comment: I meen I want this function run once automatically without clicking on foo.